# QCompleter, how to have the Id from a database

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5, qcompleter

After a LOT of searching the web without finding the right answer, I came for help from you guys... So lets see if I can explain it.

I'm working on a UI with Qt 5, and I want a `lineEdit` with auto completion. I know I can use `QCompleter`, and it works fine. I fill the `QCompleter` with a query doing a `for` iteration. But I need to know the ID of that field.

If I'm doing a query to a database that has the `Product_Name` and the `Product_Code`, the user will type the name of the product, and in each `text_edit` event I fill the `QCompleter` with new data. But, when the user selects the Product, I want to show the code in other place. Of course, there could be two or more products with the same name but different code, so I can't look for the code after the search.

So, is there a way to have two related fields in a `QCompleter`?

I already try to make a `QTableWidget` with a hidden column (with the code) and display it right on the bottom of the `QlineEdit` (to simulate the `Qcompleter`). It looks fine, and it works... but I don't know how to add the functions that `QCompleter` has, like Arrow Down will jump into the table, and make it disappear when the `lineEdit` loses focus, but not when the table is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep additional data in the completer model:

```
QMap<int, QString> data;
data[0] = "Moscow";
data[1] = "London";
data[2] = "Paris";

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(this);

QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(completer);
QMapIterator<int, QString> it(data);
while (it.hasNext())
{
    it.next();

    int code = it.key();
    QString name = it.value();

    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
    item->setText(name);
    item->setData(code, Qt::UserRole);

    model->appendRow(item);
}

completer->setModel(model);
```

Then you connect to `QCompleter` `activated(const QModelIndex &index)` signal to catch autocomplete action and display additional data you want:

```
connect(completer, SIGNAL(activated(QModelIndex)),
            this, SLOT(onItemActivated(QModelIndex)));

void Widget::onItemActivated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    int code = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toInt();

    codeEdit->setText(QString::number(code));
}
```

But this approach won't work if a user doesn't use autocompletion and types the whole string. In that case you won't be able to get correct code id if there is more than one record with the same name in the DB.

If you are trying to create some kind of a search field, I'd recommend you to display all your data in some table view and use `QSortFilterProxyModel` to show records matching user input in a line edit.